# JavaScript: Delete all iframe in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to delete all `iframe` tags using JavaScript. Already tried using `for` and `while` but none of my attempts at deleting all iframe elements work for me.

For example, let's use this RANDOM web page's HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Sugar</li>
  <li>Fruits</li>
</ul>
<iframe src="">hello</iframe>
<iframe src="">hello</iframe>
<iframe src="">hello</iframe>
<iframe src="">hello</iframe>

<p>Click the button to delete the HTML elements</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried these JavaSrcipts

Attempt 1:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  elements.parentNode.removeChild(elements);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
function myFunction() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

   while (elements.hasChildNodes()) {
     elements.removeChild(elements.lastChild);
   }
}
```

Comment: Both answers provided are good. It's a shame the site can't select multiple answers and forces you to choose just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop is the right way. Here's a simple version that will work cross-browser:

```
function myFunction() {
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

   while (elements.length) {
     elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
   }
}
```

That continually removes the last entry in the `HTMLCollection`. The `HTMLCollection` is live, so removing an element that's in that collection from the DOM also removes it from the collection, so that will reduce the `length` until eventually `length` is zero.

Answer (score 4):

On modern browsers, you can use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the NodeList directly, `.remove()`ing every iframe:

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')
  .forEach(iframe => iframe.remove());
```

Or, for ES5 compatibility:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
  function(iframe) {
    // can't use .remove: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove
    iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
  }
);
```